# How can I remove rspec from existing Rails 4 project and revert to minitest default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, minitest

I'm adding some API tests to an existing Rails 4 project which has rspec in it's Gemfile.

Since the existing project did not have any tests, and I have tests in minitest that I want to use, I'd like to know how to remove rspec from this project and revert to the Rails 4 minitest setup.

I've removed the rspec gem from the Gemfile and bundled.  I tried to manually create the Test folder and subfolders manually then run tests.  When I run 'rake' I get:

`Don't know how to build task 'default'`

I suspect I can add the test-unit and minitest gems into the Gemfile but I was hoping there was a way I could simply tell Rails 'use what you would have used if I didn't have rspec previously.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the project was originally generated with the `--skip-test-unit` flag. This results in the test unit code not being loaded, which would explain why `rake` does not invoke it.

Check `config/application.rb`. If it looks like this:

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Then uncomment the `rails/test_unit/railtie` line to ensure test unit is loaded.

Alternatively, you can replace the whole section with:

```
require "rails/all"
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.   `require "rails/test_unit/railtie"` wasn't commented, but was missing.  Once I added it, I was able to generate tests as expected.   I'd seen the `require "rails/all"` but didn't realize where to use it.